# Get the hierarchical order of a custom array list based on specific rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm

I am wanting to get the hierarchical order from the below array list.

```
var data = [
   ['','dog'],
   ['dog','cat'],
   ['dog','fish'],
   ['dog','ark'],
   ['dog','folder'],
   ['cat','blue'],
   ['cat','pencil'],
   ['cat','mouse'],
   ['fish','stencil'],
   ['fish','bread'],
   ['fish','milk'],
   ['fish','love'],
   ['mouse','tv'],
   ['mouse','oil'],
   ['mouse','car'],
   ['milk','dough'],
   ['milk','butter'],
   ['car','truck']
];
```

The way to 'calculate' this is to start at the first array of

```
['','dog']
```

Note: I will refer to the 0 index ('') as 'parent' and 1 index ('dog') as 'child'

so we want to find the arrays that have 'dog' as the parent, and then check those arrays to see if their children have any parents, if not, continuing on to the next one. (really hope this makes sense)

Below is the result of the order for my above data set.

```
var result = ['dog', 'cat', 'blue', 'pencil', 'mouse', 'tv', 'oil', 'car', 'truck', 'fish', 'stencil', 'bread', 'milk', 'dough', 'butter', 'love', 'ark', 'folder'];
```

I have attempted this with some really bad while loops and .filters() to get arrays which contain the child as the parent index, but failed.

If anyone can give some insight into this or a way to return the end result I would be most appreciative as I cannot keep figuring this out manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I think, is your algorithm.

1. Convert the source array to a nested object that uses pass-by-reference to efficiently associate parents and children.

Here's an ES6 implementation of that:

```
function pairsToIndex(pairs) {
    return pairs.reduce((index, pair, i, list) => {
        let [ parent , child ] = pair;

        let parent_exists = index.hasOwnProperty(parent);
        let child_exists = index.hasOwnProperty(child);

        if(!parent_exists) {
            index[parent] = { key: parent , children: [] };
        }

        if(!child_exists) {
            index[child] =  { key: child  , children: [] };
        }

        // now, ensure that parent-child relationship is captured
        let rel_captured = Boolean( index[parent].children.find((c) => c.key === child) );

        if(!rel_captured) {
            index[parent].children.push( index[child] );
        }

        return index;
    }, {});
}

let data = [
    ['','dog'],
    ['dog','cat'],
    ['dog','fish'],
    ['dog','ark'],
    ['dog','folder'],
    ['cat','blue'],
    ['cat','pencil'],
    ['cat','mouse'],
    ['fish','stencil'],
    ['fish','bread'],
    ['fish','milk'],
    ['fish','love'],
    ['mouse','tv'],
    ['mouse','oil'],
    ['mouse','car'],
    ['milk','dough'],
    ['milk','butter'],
    ['car','truck']
];

let x = pairsToIndex(data);
console.log(x);
```

Run that code in your browser's dev console. As you dig through the object `x`, you'll notice that each of the "children" acts like a symlink to another top-level property of `x`. In effect, each "child" is a portal to somewhere else within that object. This use of pass-by-reference sets us up for step 2...

---

2. Serialize that object by recursively traversing it in a depth-first pattern and returning the `key` prop of each node.

So, here's a short impl of that:

```
function listNode(node) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply( [node.key] , node.children.map(listNode) );
}

let out = listNode(x['']); // choosing the entry point to the hierarchy
console.log(out);
```

Note that I've had to use `apply` to avoid creating a bunch of nested, 1-element arrays (even though they would be ordered correctly). That's solvable with something like `_.flatten`, but this is a case where knowing a little more about the language obviates the need for an entire library.

Note also that `listNode` technically operates on a subtree of the hierarchy. I told it to start at the "root" node, which you've suggested is identified in the original dataset by the empty string. However, you could ask it to serialize a subset of the tree by passing it a different start point, e.g. `listNode( x['cat'] )` or `listNode( x['fish'] )`.

Finally, this algorithm is infinitely recursive. Browsers will halt this script if you feed it a very large dataset. Other JS environments (like nodejs or react-native) will not do that.

---

At this point, `out` is an array that lists each of the values from the original `data` array, in the order you're hoping for.